# How can I close a JQuery dialog using a pre-defined function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to make my dialog close after the following function:

```
function decide(category, choice, price, bool) {
  data.push([category, choice, price, earn]);
}
```

I have tried playing around with JQuery's [close method](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close). I set it as a "characteristic" of the dialog as the guide describes. Does anybody know how I can set the dialog to close after the above function has been triggered?

Would really appreciate any feedback or advice you could give me!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
function decide(category, choice, price, bool) {
  data.push([category, choice, price, earn]);
  $(selector).dialog("close");
}
```

You simply need to call the `close` method. `$(selector)` will need to be changed to represent the proper element that Dialog was initialized upon.